# unable to access data from soap api response json

Tags: api, laravel-5, soap, soap-client

I am using soap api request and its returning me [this response.](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=930878355a6d4ddfbaf068858cb15556)

That's my laravel controller code.

```
    public function testResponseSRI($phone, $code)
{
    $url = 'https://tamimahsms.com/user/bulkpush.asmx?wsdl';
    $body = '
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
    <SendSMS xmlns="https://www.tamimahsms.com/">
    <UserName>username</UserName>
    <Password>password</Password>
    <Message>test message with code '.$code.'</Message>
    <Priority>1</Priority>
    <Schdate>07/18/2018</Schdate>
    <Sender>AsifSource</Sender>
    <AppID>123456</AppID>
    <SourceRef>7654321</SourceRef>
    <MSISDNs>'.$phone.'</MSISDNs>
    </SendSMS>
    </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>';

    $headers = ['Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8', 'Content-Length: '.strlen($body)];
    $result = SoapClientRequest::send($url, $headers, $body);
    return response()->json($result);
}
```

I want to get `<StatusCode>00</StatusCode>` from `body` object.
How can I get this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I figured out. The response was not a regular JSON, firstly convert it:

```
            $data = $jsonResponse->getData();
```

Then treat it as a regular json. Now I can easily get `<StatusCode>00</StatusCode>` by using php [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

method like this:

```
if(preg_match("!<StatusCode>(.+)</StatusCode>!i",$data->body,$matches)) 
{
    return $matches[1]      // return 00
}
```